# .click function jQuery for option value drop down box

Tags: jquery

I would like to have it so that when I select an item that isn't the "select" option the item's color changes and the title "household products" text changes color as well.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#item_options')
    .click(function(){
    $('#items_title').css('color', this.select ? '#000' : '#666');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="items_title">household products</div>
<select name="items" id="item_options">
   <option value="select">Select</option>         
   <option value="towel">towel</option>
   <option value="bed">bed</option>
   <option value="blanket">blanket</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the option's color to change as it appears in the drop-down list?

Comment: When you say _I would like to have it so that when I select an item that isn't the "select" option the item's color changes and some other text changes._ do you mean you that when a user changes the value in the select box you want the css/text to change?

Comment: to clarify. i would like the options value to start on "select" and be grey. if a user pulls the drop down and selects anything other than select like "towel" then the towel text turns to black as well as the title for the drop down menu.  i hope that helps

Comment: What exactly is the problem, or what is your question?

Comment: @kontur how can i change my jQuery code so that it does what is intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="items">
    <span id="items_title">Household products:</span>
    <select name="items" id="item_options">
       <option value="select">Select</option>         
       <option value="towel">towel</option>
       <option value="bed">bed</option>
       <option value="blanket">blanket</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#items {
    color: gray;  
}

#item_options {
    color: inherit;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$( '#item_options' ).click( function () {
    $( this ).parent().css({ color: this.selectedIndex ? '#000' : '#666' });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/HdPeY/3/

Comment: @noWayhome If the "Select" option is selected, the title color is gray, and if any other option is selected, the title color is black. You didn't want that?

Comment: no how about if you select towel and towel changes color from black to grey?

Comment: @noWayhome I don't understand. The color of the selected item inside the SELECT element should change?

Comment: yes I would like both the title and the selectable options to start out as grey and turn to black if anything other than "select" is chosen.  sorry for the confusion, so much selects being thrown around

Comment: @noWayhome I've wrapped the HTML code inside a DIV, so that I can set the color on that element instead of having to set it on both the title and the dropdown box.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    if (selected == 2) {
        $('span').css({ color: 'red'});
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t5kfQ/

Answer (score 0):

try the [Change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event instead of the on click like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#item_options')
.change(function () {
    if (this.value != "select") {
        $('#items_title').css('color', this.select ? '#000' : '#666');
    }
});
 });
```

if i understood correctly this should change the background color when a user selects a value other than select value isn't select.

Comment: doesn't work for me. did you get it to work? could you show me a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` event instead of `click` event and check for `selectedIndex > 0`. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#item_options')
    .change(function(){
       $('#items_title').css('color', this.selectedIndex > 0 ? '#000' : '#666');
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: Do you want different color for each options?